# Getting App won't run without google play service which are not supported by your device only for china region

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, mobile-application

I am using location API to get the user location access in my application. It is working as expected in all the countries, but in china region it is giving following error:

"**AppName won't run without google play service which are not supported by your device**" only for china region

I have checked for the solution of above error and I got to know that this happens if google play services are not supported then this message comes, The problem is in china google play services itself is not supported in all the devices(No google play store, no google play service)

Is their any way to run google API to get location in china? If yes please help, if no then what is alternate solution to get the user location access in china.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new emulator that supports Google Play Store.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).